# Nginx Variable Cache Time

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm currently working with `fastcgi_cache` and wanted to pass a variable to `fastcgi_cache_valid` so I could have variable amount of cache time depending on the file. But it seems that it will not accept a variable.

I tried the following:

```
set $cache_time 15s;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 ${cache_time};
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $cache_time;


set $cache_time "15s";
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 ${cache_time};
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $cache_time;


set $cache_time 15;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 ${cache_time}s;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 $cache_time;
```

But I receieved the following errors:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid time value "$cache_time" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/www.com.conf:118

nginx: [emerg] directive "fastcgi_cache_valid" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/www.com.conf:118
```

Comment: Not all nginx's directives allow variables. Why you want variable here?

Comment: Define the same server in several fastcgi backend statements and each one can have its own cache value...

Comment: @AlexeyTen I want a standard cache time for all pages of a relatively low time. But I have 2-3 pages that should have a much large cache time due to taking ~5+ seconds to load and non-essential changing content only every few days or weeks.

Comment: Well, you could control cache time from fastcgi side via `x-accel-*` headers. See nginx doc for details

Answer (score 0):

---

`fastcgi_cache_valid` does not accept variable but there is a work around if you have only two options `cached` and `not-cached`.

In this example we want `cached.php` to return the cached version, and the non-cached version if the url contains params. meaning `cached.php` will always reaturn the cached version and `cached.php?id=1` will always return the non-cached version.

```
location = /cached.php {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  set $disable_cache 1;
  if ( $request_uri = "/cached.php" ){
    set $disable_cache 0;
  }
  fastcgi_cache phpcache;
  fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1h;
  fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
  fastcgi_cache_bypass $disable_cache;
  fastcgi_no_cache $disable_cache;
  add_header X-Is-Cached "Cache disabled $disable_cache";
}
```

This the content of `cached.php` used for test

```
<?php echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa")."\n";?>
```

This is the results if tests using curl

`curl --head "http://www.example.com/cached.php"`

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
 Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 17:07:55 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-Fastcgi-Cache: HIT
 X-Is-Cached: Cache disabled 0
```

`curl --head "http://www.example.com/cached.php?id=1"`

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
 Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 17:09:15 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-Fastcgi-Cache: BYPASS
 X-Is-Cached: Cache disabled 1
```

`X-Is-Cached` is used only for debuging  and it is not necessary.